# Allow members to register new members

Tags: members, registration

How can a allow Members to register new members via the control panel? I've set up the Members prefs to allow access to the Register Member entry screen. But the system does not seem to accept a new registration - just returns to the same entry screen.

Thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

There are some related options on CP > Members > Member Groups > [Edit Member Group](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/members/member_groups_edit.html):

- Can access MEMBERS section;
- Can administrate members accounts;
- Can change the group that a member is assigned to (Unlocked groups only);
- Can delete members;
- Can ban users;

Besides, you need to have at least one unlocked Member Group. Only **Super Admins** can register new members to **Locked Member Groups**. The following image shows that all Member Groups are Locked:

[image: Member groups on the Control Panel of EECMS]

Comment: Cheers, I didn't realise I needed all those options checked.